# How to get the same values for AIC and BIC in R as in Stata?

Tags: r, stata

Say I have a very simple model

```
library(foreign)

smoke <- read.dta("http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/smoke.dta")

smoking.reg <- lm(cigs ~ educ, data=smoke)

AIC(smoking.reg)
BIC(smoking.reg)
```

In R I get the following results:

```
> AIC(smoking.reg)
[1] 6520.26
> BIC(smoking.reg)
[1] 6534.34
```

Running the same regression however in Stata

```
 use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/smoke.dta
 reg cigs educ
```

returns the following result

```
estat ic
```

[image: stata output]

How can I get R to return exactly the same values as does Stata for AIC and BIC?

Comment: It looks like state is calculating the number of parameters as two, so perhaps not including the error parameter. So in r to reproduce stata set the no. of parameters to two.

Comment: ... for aic R uses `ll = logLik(smoking.reg); -2*ll + 2*3 # 3 == attr(ll, "df"))` but state does `-2*ll + 2*2`

Comment: @user20650, do you want to post this as answer?  More drastically, one could create `AIC.lm` and `BIC.lm` which would recompute based on df+1 (the loglik object also has an "nobs" attribute which would allow computing BIC ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AIC is calculated as `-2*log likelihood + 2* number of parameters`
BIC is calculated as `-2*log likelihood + log(n)* number of parameters`, where `n` is the sample size.

Your linear regression has three parameters - two coefficients and the variance -- and so you can calculate `AIC` and `BIC` as

```
ll = logLik(smoking.reg)
aic = -2*ll + 2* 3 # 6520.26
bic = -2*ll + log(nrow(smoke))* 3 # 6534.34
```

(As Ben Bolker mentioned in the comments the `logLik` object has several attributes which you can use to get the number of parameters (`"df"`) and the number of observations (`"nobs"`). See `attr(ll, "df")` and `attr(ll, "nobs")` )

Stata does not include the variance parameter, only including the number of coefficients. This usually would not be a problem as information criteria are usually used to compare models (`AIC_of_model1 - AIC_of_model2`) and so if this parameter is omitted in both calculations it will make no difference. In Stata the calculation is

```
aic = -2*ll + 2* 2 # 6518.26
bic = -2*ll + log(nrow(smoke))* 2 # 6527.647
```

Comment: This is correct. Stata doesn't count the variance parameter here.