# Calculating AIC by hand from R output

Tags: r, statistics

I am looking to calculate AIC by hand, as part of our course evaluation is a test w/o using R actively.

```
## 'data.frame':    898 obs. of  4 variables:

model_1 <- lm(rent~size+rooms,data=miete)
opt_model <- step(model_1)
## Start:  AIC=11267.31
## rent ~ size + rooms
## 
##         Df Sum of Sq       RSS   AIC
## - rooms  1    114612 251023214 11266
## <none>               250908603 11267
## - size   1  91648760 342557363 11545
## 
## Step:  AIC=11265.72
## rent ~ size
## 
##        Df Sum of Sq       RSS   AIC
## <none>              251023214 11266
## - size  1 385280616 636303830 12099
```

The formula we discussed in class is AIC = n*log(RSS)+2p, but I cant seem to achieve the results in the output using my calculator.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: check `?step` for the elements contained in opt_model, as well as `names(opt_model)` to check how to potentially access the componends from your model to add to your formula.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62307197/how-to-get-the-same-values-for-aic-and-bic-in-r-as-in-stata/62312168#62312168